# C#: Hash Multiple Strings from a Form to Class, back to the form to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, class, sha

I'm trying to figure out a way to do this.

I want to hash with a salt from my main form and post it to an SQL Server, My issue is currently I cannot seem to figure out how to call the hashed code for an SQL statement.

The issue is I can't seem to figure out how to call the hashed string into a variable or so. One of the errors I get is:

> An Object of reference for the non-static field, method, or
>   property'Functions.UniqueID'

If I tried `Functions myFunction = new Functions();`

I got:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal
>   parameter

I tried looking it up, but really just came up blank since I'm new to coding and don't quite understand all the terminology everyone throws out.

The reason why I was wanting it in a class was that I will be using this hash/salt in multiple instances of the application.

Let me show the code and maybe someone can help:

**Main Form:
Getters and Setters:**

```
        public string IdentifyOrder
        {
            get { return txtOrder.Text; }
            set { txtOrder.Text = value; }
        }
        public string IdentifyStandard
        {
            get { return cmbStandard.Text; }
            set { cmbStandard.Text = value; }
        }
        public string IdentifyNote
        {
            get { return cmbNote.Text; }
            set { cmbNote.Text = value; }
        }
```

**SQL Statement:**

```
private void btnSubmitInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Connection.MTRDataBaseConn))
                {

                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.[myDatabase] ([Purchase Order], [Standard], [Notes], [Unique Identifier]) VALUES(@PurchaseOrder,@Standard,@Notes,@UniqueIdentifier)";

                    cmd.Connection = con;

                    SqlParameter pPurchaseOrder = new SqlParameter("@PurchaseOrder", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                    SqlParameter pStandard = new SqlParameter("@Standard", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                    SqlParameter pNotes = new SqlParameter("@Notes", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                    SqlParameter pUID = new SqlParameter("@UniqueIdentifier", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);


                    pPurchaseOrder.Value = txtPurchaseOrder.Text;
                    pStandard.Value = cmbStandard.Text;
                    pNotes.Value = txtNotes.Text;
                    pUID.Value = Functions.UniqueID;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(pPurchaseOrder);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(pStandard);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(pNotes);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(pUID);

                    //execute
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                //catch error
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
       }
```

**My Class"Functions":**

```
public class Functions
    {
        public readonly MainForm Identifiers;
        public Functions(MainForm Identifiers)
        {
            this.Identifiers = Identifiers;
        }

        public void GenerateUniqueIdentifier()
        {
            string orderID = Identifiers.IdentifyOrder;
            string standardID = Identifiers.IdentifyStandard;
            string noteID = Identifiers.IdentiftNote;

           string salt = "" + orderID + "" + standardID + "" + noteID + "";
        }

        public String GenHash(String input, String salt)
        {
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input + salt);
            System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed sha256hashstring =
                new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed();
            byte[] hash = sha256hashstring.ComputeHash(bytes);

            return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
        }

        public string UniqueID { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: The error seems to refer to the point where you create the Function class (somewhere you have a _new Functions(....)_) but you don't show that code...

Comment: Where exactly you are using the generated Hash in your code? You want to store the Hash in the database?

Comment: I meant to post that error as a reference to other thing's I've tried. @ChetanRanpariya I would like to store the hashed code in a variable. Meaning the Finished hash.. I think.. I'm really new to this.

Comment: UniqueID is the property which you want to use to access the Hash from `Functions` class? You want to generate hash for each input value of the form?

Comment: btnSubmitInfo is in the same form (MainForm) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an object of `Functions` class and then call methods on it or access properties of it.

Something like as following.

```
//Previous code...

var functionsObj = new Functions(mainForm); // You need to pass the
     // object of class MainForm as argument to Functions constructor 
     //If this code is running in code behind for "MainForm" then you can do as following.
var functionObj = new Functions(this);
pPurchaseOrder.Value = txtPurchaseOrder.Text;
pStandard.Value = cmbStandard.Text;
pNotes.Value = txtNotes.Text;
pUID.Value = functionsObj.UniqueID;

//Next Code....
```

This should resolve the issue.

Comment: I've tried this, I tried it again to see it it was me, however. This returns Error: `There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'Identifiers' of 'Functions.Functions(MainForm)'`

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm. I had to use `var functionObj = new Functions(this);`